# How to save xarray in human readable format like csv, excel etc?

Tags: python-xarray

I am new to xarray data structure. I have xarrary data variable (intensity_table) which looks like following in the image. This xarrary structure comes from the postprocess of tif images. The tif image has 6 Round and 3 Channels. Intensity_table compute normalize intensity in these images and save it in features. I want to see this feature variable for each image separately. Is there any way to read this data in easy format or save in text file so that I can read from anywhere.
Thanks a lot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can convert it to a pandas dataframe first, did you try https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_pandas.html?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - instead use `print(da)` to get a string representation of the array which you can paste into the question and [format as a code block](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

Both Datasets and DataArrays have [`xr.DataArray.to_pandas`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_pandas.html) and [`xr.Dataset.to_pandas`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_pandas.html) methods. once you're in pandas, you can write to a variety of tabular data formats including, e.g. with [`pd.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

If you'd like to preserve all non-indexing coordinates in the result, you might prefer to convert the data to a long-form table with each coordinate a column and all dimensions as levels in a MultiIndex. In that case, first convert the DataArray to a Dataset, then write this to a dataframe with [`xr.Dataset.to_dataframe()`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_dataframe.html):

```py
df = intensity_table.to_dataset(name='IntensityTable').to_dataframe()
df.to_csv(filepath, index=True)
```

Note, however, that because pandas/CSV do not have any way of representing multiple datasets with different sets of dimensions, preserving all non-index coordinates will first broadcast all non-index coordinates and variables against each other. So all of your variables indexed only by `features` will be repeated for each element in `r` and `c`.

Comment: This is the answer I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: glad it helped. if this ended up being the best answer for the question, please [follow this guide to selecting a correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)